Where do the variables in Van der Waerden's definition of the alternating group come from?
Van der Waerden defines the symmetric group $\mathscr{G}_n$ of a finite set $\mathscr{M}$ with $n$ elements as the group of its permutations. Later, he introduces the alternating group in the following way:

The most important subgroup of the symmetric group $\mathscr{G}_n$ of all permutations on $n$ objects is the alternating group $\mathscr{U}_n$, containing those permutations which, when applied to variables $x_1, \ldots{}, x_n$ carry the function
$$ \Delta = \Pi_{i<k} (x_i - x_k) $$
into itself.

What I'm struggling to grasp is where these variables $x_1, \ldots{}, x_n$ are coming from, and what we know about them. Are they simply to be understood as any arbitrary finite-sequence of $n$ elements with a subtraction operation defined analogously to that of the integers?

"Are they simply..." : that's the right way to understand the formula.

Search for the signum of permutaions to understand it. The variables $x_1,\ldots ,x_n$ come from the group $S_n$, which are bijections of the set ${1,2,\ldots ,n}$. For these $n$ letters, we have the variables $x_1,\ldots ,x_n$.

@DietrichBurde please elaborate? I don't understand what is meant by "signum of permutations".

See this post for example. The kernel of the sign map (signum map) is the alternating group. You can read in this post: Consider the polynomial in $n$ variables given by  $\prod_{1\leq i < j \leq n} (x_j-x_i)$ and the obvious action that $S_n$ has on the indices of those variables.

The question is not clear. What is your definition of the alternating group? This definition is quite standard, apart from the slightly odd way of avoiding the sign function.

@tomasz Well, the usual definition (e.g. as in Wikipedia) is that it's the set of even permutations, where even means sign +1, so I think the question is about "the slightly odd way of avoiding the sign function." I think OP just wants some motivation or perhaps a proof that it's equivalent to the usual definition. Or, the idea of formal variables $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ is not so clear.

@JairTaylor: I wouldn't be so sure, judging by the comments.

@tomasz My difficulty is I don't understand where the variables $x_1, \ldots{}, x_n$ come from in the context in Van der Waerden. He doesn't introduce them as belonging to any particular set or group, so when he uses subtraction and a product it's a bit confusing. He doesn't say that they're integers or something of the like in the context.

@akiarie: They are just formal variables. They are not meant to represent anything other than themselves. (At least they do not need to, I do not know what he had in mind.)

@tomasz I think that make sense. Is it normal to introduce a set of formal variables without clarifying the set over which they're varying, or stating that they are merely formal? It seems to be an awfully informal way to use such formalism.

I think the more precise way of saying it would be to consider the action of $S_n$ on the ring $\mathbb{Q}[x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n]$ and consider the subgroup that fixes this particular element.

@akiarie: Perfectly normal. Unless you want to go and start plugging things in, it doesn't really matter. Slightly more formally, you can think of a free commutative ring extension of some sort (or equivalently, a polynomial ring), but explicitly saying that is not really important if you don't want to study these objects in depth.

Note the elements of $\mathscr G_n$ permute the $x_i.$  (Consider the action on the indices.)
The polynomial just serves to recognize,  with a minus sign, each time $i$ and $j$ are swapped, since $x_j-x_i=-(x_i-x_j).$
Since even permutations are products of an even number of transpositions,  there are always an even number of swaps, the minus signs cancel,  and the polynomial remains invariant under the elements of $\mathscr U_n.$
